# Removing the index column in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I write into a csv file using pandas and find there is a numeric index column in the csv file. I tired reset_index(drop = True) but it still stays in the first column. How do I remove that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/658uL.png)

Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html  check `index=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the `index` column while saving the `csv`, you can use [`index=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). Here is an example:

```
#assuming df is your dataframe
df.to_csv('Yourfile.csv',index=False)
```

**Example**:

```
#generating some test data
>>> from pandas import util
>>> df = util.testing.makeDataFrame()
>>> df = df.head()
>>> df
                   A         B         C         D
hRACSnElRI  0.859179 -0.347567  1.750585  0.399515
icq8SOqHuD  1.978926 -0.491209 -0.674014  0.073224
WrcyQudgbD  1.321713  1.226830  1.806624  0.821147
8JeGcvp7Pw -1.033936  1.544080 -0.688740  0.800279
0pkg0966C3 -1.955992 -0.034661 -0.648781 -0.741877

#saving csv with no index column
>>> df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
```

**Output in the `test.csv`**:

```
A,B,C,D
0.8591789837360452,-0.34756727971713336,1.7505852695289563,0.39951524594334664
1.9789261120517005,-0.4912087678911003,-0.6740137161793854,0.07322370848561688
1.3217129370700997,1.2268304767550358,1.8066236997397453,0.8211473024218794
-1.0339361010450239,1.5440802503340652,-0.6887403441202857,0.8002786894217319
-1.955992286061844,-0.034660953939963234,-0.6487814076862116,-0.7418769734622875
```

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider check-marking/accepting the question

Answer (score 1):

Just try to give `index=False` in `to_csv()`.  As mentioned by @grayrigel